# I don't see No Update on Category design backend

Tags: custom-layout-update

In Magento 2.3.4-p2 with Luma, when I try to save category in the backend I get this error message, "Something went wrong when saving the category", and I can't find out what is going on, but I realized that select in design -> Custom Layout Update is empty, I believe it should contain "NO Update". Does anyone have any ideas?

This is content from var / log / exception.log

[2020-06-17 10:08:53] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE [23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`photocolor_photocolor_m2`.`catalog_category_entity_varchar`, CONSTRAINT `CAT_CTGR_ENTT_VCHR_ENTT_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity2` (...), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar` ( `attribute_id`, `_ ?`, `?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`value `= VALUES (` value`) {"exception": "[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception (code: 23000): SQLSTATE [23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`photocolor_photocolor_m2`.`catalog_category_entity_varchar`, CONSTRAINT` CAT_CTGR_ENTT_VCHR_ENTT_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID `FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`` REF_ENCENT`catalog_category ... catalog_category ,`store_id`,` entit y_id`,` value`) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` value `= VALUES (`value`) at / home / photocolor / public_html / vendor / magento / framework / DB / Statement / Pdo /Mysql.php:110, PDOException (code: 23000): SQLSTATE [23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`photocolor_photocolor_m2`.`catalog_category_entity_varchar`, CONSTRAINT` CAT_CT_TGR_T_GR_T FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity2` (...) at /home/photocolor/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91) "} []

Comment: I think you should check in ROOT_FOLDER/var/log/exception.log

Comment: I edited and put the exceptiond.log error.